# Android Webview fullscreen video working inconsistently

Tags: java, android, webview, video-streaming, android-fullscreen

Mostly my android webview works fine when fullscreening videos but there are some videos where it encounters problems, some I've already fixed, some I can't

1) Fullscreen button doesn't always trigger `onShowCustomView`. FIXED: Updating Chrome from the Google app store fixes this bug

2) Video goes fullscreen and you can hear the audio but sometimes the whole screen is black, you cannot even see the video player UI. Example: https://www.engadget.com/2019/05/22/vader-immortal-review-oculus-quest-vr/ 
I have a hack fix for this at the moment by resizing the view after a 2s delay but I'd obviously prefer a more robust solution

3) Video goes fullscreen temporarily but then closes itself immediately. This only happens occasionally but I've seen it happen when opening vimeo videos from twitter. It's not consistent so you'll have to click through a few https://mobile.twitter.com/search?q=Vimeo&src=typed_query

Any idea how I can make this work more consistently?

My custom web chrome client:

```
public void onShowCustomView(View paramView, CustomViewCallback paramCustomViewCallback)
{
    if (this.mCustomView != null)
    {
        onHideCustomView(); // I verified this wasn't the cause of point 3
        return;
    }
    this.mCustomView = paramView;
    this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = browserUi.getBrowser().getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
    previousOrientation = browserUi.getBrowser().getRequestedOrientation();

    this.mCustomViewCallback = paramCustomViewCallback;
    FrameLayout decorView;
    if(browserUi.isPreviewWindow()){
        decorView = browserUi.getBrowser().findViewById(R.id.prev_window_fullscreen_video_container);
    }else {
        decorView = browserUi.getBrowser().findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_video_container);
    }
    decorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    decorView.addView(this.mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));

    if(!browserUi.isPreviewWindow()) {
        this.mCustomView.setKeepScreenOn(true); // prevents sleep while viewing

        int flags = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        flags |= SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        flags |= SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
        flags |= SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        flags |= SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
        flags |= SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
        int screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        browserUi.getBrowser().setRequestedOrientation(screenOrientation);
    }
}
```